Does quantum tunnelling have anything to with perception of light?
There have been studies suggesting that the sense of smell has something to do with quantum tunnelling but I'm afraid I don't know the exact details.
Do we possess internal mechanisms that simply "recognize" a photon of light when we see one, or is light somehow absorbed into the nervous system?
Does quantum tunnelling have anything to do with the perception of light by humans?

What if tunneling isn't part of vision. You still have physical interactions in the eye producing experiences. Light is absorbed in the retina, producing nerve impulses. The impulses flow into the brain, where they influence the mind. The mechanism of the brain is understood much less well than the eye. But interesting as it is, the brain is off topic here. If you would care for answers about the physics of absorption in the retina, you might get answers.

As for the mind, the comments to my answer to this might be of interest. How is energy "stored in an electric field"?

@mmesser324, thank you, I did not realise brain questions were off topic. However, answers about the physics of absorption in the retina may help greatly.

It isn't that brain related questions are off topic. It is that questions about the mind are not answerable with physics. Many interesting questions about it cannot be answered at all. Questions about the brain are more likely about biology, or perhaps chemistry, than physics. We just know more about physics, and answer those kinds of questions here. If you come up with a question about the physics of the brain, ask away.

Questions about perception of light can be on topic. Here is one. Search and you will find more. What is Gray, from a physics POV?

Or see the Wikipedia article on Color science. It is a stub, but has lots of links.

The neurophysiological mechanisms by which the retina converts photons into nerve impulses do not involve tunneling. The functioning of the retina in this regard is scientifically well-understood.

@niels-nielson thank you, that is all I needed to know
